# Junit using eq() argument matcher vs passing string directly

Tags: junit, mockito

What is the use of `eq()` argument matcher if passing the string directly will do the same thing.

e.g. the behaviour of

```
when(method.foo("test")).thenReturn("bar");
```

is similar to

```
when(method.foo(ArgumentMatcher.eq("test"))).thenReturn("bar");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more ArgumentMatchers than `eq()`. Another popular one is `any()`, but there are many more [ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html). They are generally used together to help identify the correct value for the test case. You may not want to check all args in all tests. For example, if there were more params in your code.

`when(method.foo(eq("test"), any(Test.class), isNull()).thenReturn("bar");`

I agree that `eq()` seems redundant, but the trick is if one argument uses a matcher all must, so if you want to use one `any()` you can no longer just put an unwrapped `String` argument.